# Are Spring Cloud Config profiles hard-coded or special in any way?

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I am getting started with Spring Cloud Config through a JHipster microservice application. I see the default profiles of dev and prod. I would really like to have multiple dev profiles for each customer. e.g. devCustomer1, devCustomer2, multiple test profiles: testCustomer1, testCustomer2, and multiple production profiles: prodCustomer1, prodCustomer2...

(each customer needs a separate database and customizations)

Can I just rename the profiles and have it read data from a Git repo for dev/test/prod as renamed, or are "dev" and "prod" special keywords that must not be changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is in no way hardcoded, you can use your apps `spring.cloud.config.profile` property to override the list of profiles.

See: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.1.RELEASE/#_locating_remote_configuration_resources